# MOD REWRITE (htaccess) how to rewrite: index.php?lang=$1&pagePL=$2

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to rewrite:

```
index.php?lang=$1&pagePL=$2
```

so that I have only `mydomain.com/(value of pagePL)`

?

This is my attepmt but it does not work...

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?lang=$1&pagePL=$2 [L]
```

This is my htaccess file:

```
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 php
    Options FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?lang=pl [L]
    RewriteRule ^en/?$ index.php?lang=en [L]
    RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)$ index.php?lang=$1&pageEN=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?lang=$1&pagePL=$2 [L]
```

It works for english version of the site:

```
http://nabalkany.hekko24.pl/en/menu
```

but it does not work for:

```
http://nabalkany.hekko24.pl/menu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have 1 capture group so `lang=$1&` should be removed from the redirect path and `$2` should become `$1`.

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?pagePL=$1 [L]
```